# how to display network image content without download it like whatsapp?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How does WhatsApp show network image without download it?

In Flutter,

```
Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9');
```

like this

[image: please check this image]

Comment: Without downloading it's not possible. And regarding WhatsApp showing preview, WhatsApp should be downloading the thumbnail image behind the scene .

Answer (score 0):

what whatsapp does is, when a media is uploaded a thumbnail will be created on server, initially the thumbnail will be downloaded and shown to the user on pressing download original image is downloaded there is no magic in it.

```
if(!downloaded){
 return Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?imageThumbnail=9&');
} else {
 return Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9&');
}
```